# How can I write SSE instruction in C for two for loops?

Tags: c, for-loop, sse, vectorization

Using the library 'immintrin.h', I am able to write SSE instruction for simple for loops and operations. However, how can I write SSE instructions for the shown statement?

```
for (int i =0; i<n; i++){
   for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
     x[i] += a[i] + a[j];
}}
```

x and a are float* initialised using _mm_malloc(). memory access pattern can be used as __m128 and an unrolling strategy for 4 bytes.

I'm sorry if I'm not too clear, but just like

```
for (int i = 0; i < vecsize; i+=4) {
        __m128 a  = _mm_load_ps(a+i);
        __m128 x  = _mm_add_ps(x,a);
        _mm_store_ps(x+i, x);
    }
```

(which is for 1 loop only), I'd like something similar for the loops shown above.

Edit:  I (EricPostpischil) am injecting this text from a comment, because it is **important** to the problem statement. The author, NeilDA, should expand upon this:

> **… in my program 'a' is always changing and hence I want 'x' that changes with it.**

**I HAVE MANAGED TO DO IT!! I submitted the answer..**

Comment: You have not told us what types `x` and `a` are. Do you already know how you want to run the loops? What memory access pattern you desire.

Comment: x and a are float* initialised using _mm_malloc(). Using _m128? if that makes sense? sorry i'm new to this.

Comment: Thanks. But please don't add that in a comment. Make an edit to the question. We don't want to have to read the comments in order to understand the question. And also any ideas on vectorization strategy would help. If you have none, say so. If you have decided already on strategy, but can't implement, say so. Makes a huge impact on what the Q is.

Comment: Ok i'll edit the previous and this one in the main question. a strategy of unrolling with vector size (N/4)*4?

Comment: What compiler are you using? Have you looked at the generated code? I'd pretty much expect `gcc` in modern variants to make this into SSE anyway, and whilst I haven't used recent versions of MSVC, I do believe it is capable of doing some pretty clever stuff too.

Comment: yes i'm using gcc compiler. also im just measuring how fast the above code runs using SSE as compared to normal C

Comment: What do you mean "normal C"? You cannot compare SSE with normal C. That makes no sense. C is a high level language. SSE is an ISA. You compiler can compile your C down to SSE instructions. It probably does so already, or can readily be made to do so with appropriate compiler options.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but are you able to understand now from my edit?

Comment: I take it that above you mean x[i] += a[i] + a[j], not x[i] = ? i.e. accumulating process?

Comment: Oh no :P YES YES. My bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
__m128 x_v, a_v, aj_v;
for (int i = 0; i < (vec_size); i+=4) {
            x_v = _mm_load_ps(x + i);
            a_v = _mm_load_ps(a+i);
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            aj_v = _mm_set1_ps(a[j]);
            x_v = _mm_add_ps(x_v, _mm_add_ps(aj_v, a_v));
        }
            _mm_store_ps(x + i, x_v);
    }
```

**I don't know if it can be improved even further, but this cut down my time from 0.17 s to 0.04s :D
Any remarks or ways to improve it would be great!**

Comment: One difference with the original non-vectorized version is that `a_v` stays constant in the inner loop. The other thing that worries me is this code relies on compilers not doing fancy loop transform optimizations since the fact that `a` is being updated concurrently is not communicated to the compiler with an atomic or volatile load. I'll edit my answer to include a version that re-load `a_v` in the inner loop for completeness.

Comment: According to the question that you asked, @Eric's answer is far better. So it looks like you answered a different question. Without a clear statement of the problem, this question is a bit of a wild goose chase.

Answer (score 3):

This is only a partial answer, but it is too long/detailed for a comment.

I question whether your problem is written correctly. As shown, for each `x[i]`, it adds `a[i]` *n* times and adds each `a[j]` once, for 0≤*j*<*n*. So it is equivalent to:

```
sum = 0;
for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    sum += a[j];
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    x[i] += n*a[i] + sum;
```

This would be implemented with much simpler SSE code than other likely array operations. And, of course, simply rewriting it as above would produce much faster code than the original formulation.

Comment: Hmmm.. I can write SSE for 2 for loops like this that are not nested. It might work, I'll try it. Thanks

Comment: It doesnt work I'm afraid. I'm working on something dynamic that requires constant update of x value..

Comment: @NeilDa: Then you have not stated the problem correctly and completely. You should show a [short, self-contained compilable example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the computation you want to perform. In the problem you stated, no “constant update” of `x` is involved.

Comment: @NeilDA Your first task is to work out what the problem is. At the moment you don't understand what problem you are trying to solve. This answer converts your algo from O(N^2) to O(N). No amount of SSE can do that. You need to go back to the drawing board and understand the problem deeply before attempting to optimise. You are wasting everyone's time, especially your own, until you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
__m128 *mx = (__m128*)x;
__m128 *ma = (__m128*)a;
__m128 temp_a;

for (int i = 0; i < (n>>2); ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < (n>>2); ++j) {
        temp_a = _mm_add_ps(*(ma+i), *(ma+j));
        *mx = _mm_add_ps(*mx, temp_a);
    }
    mx++;
}
```

You would have to make sure that `n` is a multiple of 4 of course, and make sure that x is initialized to 0 so that the accumulation is correct.

Comment: I had used slightly different code and got the same outcome what your code shows. What is happening is if some x is supposed to go from A to B, it is only going up to the halfway point. However, the simple nested for loops above take x all the way. Thanks anyway. I give up for the night.

Answer (score 0):

Transform:

```
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            x[i] += a[i] + a[j];
```

into:

```
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        x[i] += n*a[i] + sum(a));
```

See `f_sse()` in the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

enum {
    N = 4,
};

float x[N], a[N] = { .1, .2, .3, .4 }, y[N];

void f(float *x, float *a, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            x[i] += a[i] + a[j];
}

float array_sum(float *a, int n)
{
    /* could be vectorized as well */
    int i;
    float s;
    for (s = 0, i = 0; i < n; i++)
        s += a[i];
    return s;
}

void f_sse(float *x, float *a, int n)
{
    int i, l;
    float t;
    __m128 sum_a, n_vec;
    t = array_sum(a, n);
    sum_a = _mm_set1_ps(t);
    n_vec = _mm_set1_ps(n);
    l = n / 4;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i += 4) {
        __m128 ai, xi;
        ai = _mm_load_ps(a + i);
        xi = _mm_load_ps(x + i);
        ai = _mm_mul_ps(ai, n_vec);
        ai = _mm_add_ps(ai, sum_a);
        xi = _mm_add_ps(xi, ai);
        _mm_store_ps(x + i, xi);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i, r;
    f(x, a, N);
    f_sse(y, a, N);
    r = memcmp(x, y, N);
    if (r == 0)
        return 0;
    printf("x: { ");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf("%f, ", x[i]);
    printf("}\n");
    printf("y: { ");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf("%f, ", y[i]);
    printf("}\n");
    return 3;
}
```

Since you state that `a` is being updated concurrently and you can't do the loop transform above. You need to make a conscious decision on when to take updates from `a`. It'll never match the original non-vectorized version since we're loading 4 floats at a time.

Re-loads `a[j]` in inner loop:

```
void f_sse(float *x, float *a, int n)
{
    int i, j, l;
    l = n / 4;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i += 4) {
        __m128 ai, xi;
        ai = _mm_load_ps(a + i);
        xi = _mm_load_ps(x + i);
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            /* re-load a[j] to get updates */
            xi = _mm_add_ps(xi, _mm_add_ps(ai, _mm_set1_ps(((volatile float *)a)[j])));
        }
        _mm_store_ps(x + i, xi);
    }
```

}

Re-loads `a[j]` and `(a + i)` in inner loop:

```
void f_sse(float *x, float *a, int n)
{
    int i, j, l;
    l = n / 4;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i += 4) {
        __m128 ai, xi;
        xi = _mm_load_ps(x + i);
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            /* re-load (a + i) to get updates */
            ai = _mm_load_ps(a + i);
            /* re-load a[j] to get updates */
            xi = _mm_add_ps(xi, _mm_add_ps(ai, _mm_set1_ps(((volatile float *)a)[j])));
        }
        _mm_store_ps(x + i, xi);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but it doesn't seem to work with my program. I cannot post the whole thing here and I understand it would be hard for you to understand as well. :(

Comment: However, does this change x dynamically? because in my program 'a' is always changing and hence I want 'x' that changes with it.

Comment: @NeilDA, I think you need to consciously decide **when** to accept newly updated content from `a` in your algorithm. E.g. you could recalculate `sum_a` at each step in the loop. The proper answer will depend on how `a` is updated concurrently.

Comment: Can you look at the answer i've provided if its correct or not? I have answered my own question.

Comment: Thanks so much Scott. I used it. There's no visible change on the run that I can see but I guess this is a more efficient/appropriate version. Cheers :)